# Python logbook - how to dynamically control logging level

Tags: python, logging

I have recently switched from using 'logging' to 'logbook'.
So far, so good, but I am missing one critical functionality - ability to change the minimum level during runtime.
In 'logging', I can call myLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO), but there is no equivalent method in logbook.
Anyone?

Comment: from logbook import logger and you can set the logging levels. For more info have look in the below link " http://pythonhosted.org/Logbook/quickstart.html"

Comment: The question was not how to set the initial level (which is done in the constructor) but rather afterwards. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple (and undocumented) - modify the 'level' attribute:
myLogger.level = logbook.INFO